# Why is C++ 14.0 required to install python-jose

Tags: python, pip, python-jose

I'm getting this error when I issue pip install python-jose on Windows:

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

I'm confused as why I need to install Visual C++ 14.0?

Comment: You need a C compiler to build [pycrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto).

Comment: Is there a way to get the python-jose installed without compiling locally, I don't really want to install VC++ just to use this feature.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pycrypto+windows